# Prove that the product of lower triangular matrices with ones in the diagonal is a lower triangular matrix with ones in the diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I need help with this excersice:
"Suppose $L$ and $M$ are lower triangular matrices with
ones on the diagonal. Show that $LM$ is lower triangular with
ones on the diagonal" This exercise is taken from
Elementary Linear Algebra - Stanley I. Grossman 7th edition.

[Hint: If $B=LM$ prove that $b_{ii}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}l_{ik}m_{ki}=1$ and $b_{ij}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}l_{ik}m_{kj}=0$ , if $j>i$].

But I'm stuck, I really don't know where to start. I really apreciate for your help.

Comment: For matrices $L,M$, since they are upper triangular with ones on the diagonal, we must have $l_{ii}= m_{ii} = 1$ and $l_{ij} = m_{ij}=0$ for $j>i$.

Comment: The proof is straightforward form the definition of matrix product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us call a lower triangular matrix with a diagonal of 1 a **LD1-matrix**.

Instead of working with indices, I advise you to prove it by induction on the size $n$ of the matrices considered as an upper left block of size $n-1$ bordered by a line vector, a column vector and a real entry, like this:

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}L_1&0\\U&1\end{pmatrix}}_L\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}L_2&0\\V&1\end{pmatrix}}_M=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}L_3&S\\W&a\end{pmatrix}}_B\tag{1}$$

with the aim to prove three

Objectives: prove that $L_3$ is an LD1-matrix, $S=0$ (null vector) and $a=1.$

(in this way $B$ will be a LD1-matrix of order $n$).

Let us write down the 4 block equations equivalent to (1),

$$\begin{cases}L_1L_2&=&L_3\\0&=&S\\UL_2+V&=&W\\1&=&a\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

and make a reasoning by induction (i.e., we assume that $L_1,L_2$ are LD1-matrices.).

The first equation in (2) is where the induction step is used: $L_3$ is an LD1 matrix as product of two LD1 matrices (with dimension $n-1$).  The second and fourth equations in (2) fullfill the two other objectives.

Remark: The third equation doesn't bring information.

Comment: Sorry, I was inactive for a while. Yes, I like it this way. I think that is easier.